# Fail to compile a python script with dependencies

Tags: python, compilation, dependencies, executable, portability

I have a tiny (70 lines) python script and I need an executable which includes all the dependencies of the script. It should be usable on windows, where `python-magic` is only usable in connection with cygwin.

Now I've tried to use Nuitka, which gives me a 6MB executable, however it's not executable on windows, as it states it's not a valid executable, without any further information on why it's not.

Then I've been told to try `cx_freeze`, which I'm unable to install. `Pip` states my python version is incompatible. (tried it with pip and pip3 and python is installed..)

How could I get an executable for windows, including all dependencies from my python script written on a Unix system.

Windows system: Windows 8.1 64bit

Unix system: Debian Testing; Python 2.7 and 3.4 installed

Comment: which version of python are you running? which version of windows?

Comment: I edited the op, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using python 2.7 on windows 8.1 and pyinstaller works perfectly fine.
If you want to compile an exe file which can be ported without any DLL files or anything you should use the following pyinstaller command:

```
python pyinstaller.py --onefile your_script_file.py
```

Comment: I just tried it with a script juts containing `import magic; print('hello')`. With your command I get an executable (4MB) - which however doesn't run on my testing Windows XP. It states `"Program too big to fit in memory"`

Comment: Did you compile your executable on a windows machine?
If you intend to run the program on windows machine try compiling it on a windows machine and see if that works.

Comment: I compiled it on a debian jessie.. that was the initial idea, so that I don't have to get `python-magic` working on a windows machine.. but I'll try to do so..

Comment: Try to get python-magic working on windows and then compile the executable on windows as well. I'm not sure if it works but it might be worth a try.

Comment: I've just checked the executable and it has an ELF file header.. so no wonder it doesn't run on windows.. I'm currently installing cygwin..

Comment: If I'd get `python-magic` working, I think it would work.. up to now I haven't been able to do so..

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller), it is very useful to make any executable. And If you need a windows executable you have to compile it on Windows!

Comment: I'll try `pyinstaller`, thanks! Anything to look out for, when using it to compile a portable executable?

Comment: Why do you need a portable executable if python itself is portable? Use the script..., Add upside `#!/anv/python` and add to the file the executable permission (on *nix  `chmod x+a file.py`). In this way, if python is installed and there are libraries, you can execute it directly.